# PagerSnapHelper smooth scroll to the top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling

I have a screen with a RecyclerView with vertical orientation.
I have derived `PagerSnapHelper` to allow smooth-scrolling vertically, one item at a time. The problem is that the RecyclerView scrolls putting the current `page` in the center. I need it at the top.

Is that possible?

Comment: I think for this u have to customize the Snapping logic . There r few Custom layout manager available which provide this type of snapping [Like this one](https://github.com/xmuSistone/VegaLayoutManager). it has a custom snapping implementation you can take a look . [here is another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806065/recyclerview-pagersnaphelper-snap-on-start-top-instead-of-center-android).